# Bottle app does not process routes put into a separate module within a package

Tags: python, bottle

I have this directory structure:

```
.
├── controller
│   ├── FooController.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│
├── main.py
```

`FooController`:

```
from bottle import get, post, request, response, run, abort, \
                   redirect, LocalResponse
import json

@get('/')
def create():
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return json.dumps({'hello2' : 'world'})
```

I execute python `main.py` which has:

```
from controller import *
from bottle import get, post, request, response, run, abort, \
                   redirect, LocalResponse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
```

I was hoping that that by importing all controllers (in this case `FooController`), it would hook into the framework. But it doesn't when I go to localhost:8080/ I get a 404 error. If I put all my routes into `main.py`, it works.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: By the way, module names (`FooController.py`) are usually made lowercase, this is to avoid problems on case-insensitive filesystems. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way to modularize your app, but

```
from controller.FooController import *
```

is the proper way to do the import, and it'll fix your 404 error.

Comment: Yea that works. Still need to learn some more about modules in Python. Thanks